# Does Windows 8 have a Status Bar to display details of a file?

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 7, when I select a video file in Windows Explorer it displays information about that file at the bottom of the window. For example:

[image]

However this seems to have been removed in Windows 8. Is there anyway I can get this feature back?

**EDIT**: I know I can always open the Details Pane, but that's not what I want. I want it to be at **bottom** of the window, not at the side

Comment: note: there is actually a something called status bar, in Folder Options under the View tab.

Comment: True - The Status bar can be activated thru "Options" under the View tab - But the details shown are quite minimal - It shows the number of files in the folder, and on selecting a file, it shows the file size too. But if you were looking for more details, the Details pane is helpful.

Comment: This is called the Details Pane, and it's still there in Windows 8.

Comment: Yeah, they [shifted the Details Pane to the right](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/08/29/improvements-in-windows-explorer.aspx) and left only a single-line status bar at the bottom. You'll probably need to wait for some sort of hack (if possible) to move the pane back down. Not everyone has a widescreen monitor, so why couldn't they have made the location an option, or even made it draggable? Pane ITA is what it is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to edit system files.

After you modify the system files, you may have the details pane at the bottom and the preview pane on the right simultaneously.

[image: windows 8 pane - status at bottom]

### Instructions

- Copy `%WinDir%\System32\shell32.dll` and `%WinDir%\SysWOW64\shell32.dll` to the desktop or to temporary directories.
- Take ownership of and rename the original `shell32.dll` files.

  - Save `Rename shell32.dll.bat`:

    ```
    takeown /f "%WinDir%\System32\shell32.dll"
    icacls "%WinDir%\System32\shell32.dll" /grant Administrators:F
    ren "%WinDir%\System32\shell32.dll" "shell32.dll.bak"

    takeown /f "%WinDir%\SysWOW64\shell32.dll"
    icacls "%WinDir%\SysWOW64\shell32.dll" /grant Administrators:F
    ren "%WinDir%\SysWOW64\shell32.dll" "shell32.dll.bak"
    ```
  - Right click on `Rename shell32.dll.bat` > Run as administrator > Yes.
- Repeat the following steps for each `shell32.dll` on the desktop or in temporary directories:

  - Right click on `shell32.dll` > Properties > For "Attributes", disable "Read-only" > OK.
  - You will need either [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/), [Anolis Resourcer](http://www.anol.is/resourcer/), or [Restorator](http://www.bome.com/products/restorator/downloads).
  - Resource Hacker

    - File > Open ... > Select the `shell32.dll` file.
    - UIFILE

      - 3 > 1033 > Replace text > Compile Script:

        ```
        <duixml>
        <Element resid="FolderLayout" layout="shellborderlayout()" sheet="genericlayoutstyle">
        <StatusBarModule ModuleID="StatusBarModule" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()"/>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewContainer)" height="53rp" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()">
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewShineLayer)"/>
        <PreviewBackground id="atom(BackgroundClear)" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)" layout="borderlayout()">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="PreviewThumbnailModule" MaxThumbSize="256" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element layoutpos="Client" layout="filllayout()">
        <PreviewMetadata ModuleID="PreviewMetadataModule" NullSelectPropertyString="prop:*System.OfflineStatus;*System.OfflineAvailability" layoutpos="Client"/>
        </Element>
        </PreviewBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(PreviewPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(PreviewContainer)" FramePersistType="2" SlidesUpAndDown="true" layoutpos="top" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(ReadingPane)" layout="filllayout()" layoutpos="right">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="ReadingPaneThumbnailModule" HideProperty="PreviewHandlerRunning" Vertical="true" layoutpos="client" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)"/>
        <ReadingPaneModule ModuleID="ReadingPaneModule" layoutpos="none"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(ReadingPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(ReadingPane)" GrowTargetFirst="true" SlidesUpAndDown="false" PrioritySizer="atom(PageSpaceControlSizer)" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false" FramePersistType="2" layoutpos="Right"/>
        <ProperTreeModule id="atom(ProperTree)" ModuleID="ProperTreeModule" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element id="atom(ViewHostContainer)" layoutpos="Client" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layout="borderlayout()">
        <ViewHost id="atom(clientviewhost)" layout="borderlayout()" layoutpos="client">
        </ViewHost>
        </Element>
        </Element>
        </duixml>
        ```
      - 4 > 1033 > Replace text > Compile Script:

        ```
        <duixml>
        <Element resid="FolderLayout" layout="shellborderlayout()" sheet="musiclayoutstyle">
        <StatusBarModule ModuleID="StatusBarModule" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()"/>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewContainer)" height="53rp" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()">
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewShineLayer)"/>
        <PreviewBackground id="atom(BackgroundClear)" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)" layout="borderlayout()">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="PreviewThumbnailModule" MaxThumbSize="256" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element layoutpos="Client" layout="filllayout()">
        <PreviewMetadata ModuleID="PreviewMetadataModule" NullSelectPropertyString="prop:*System.OfflineStatus;*System.OfflineAvailability" layoutpos="Client"/>
        </Element>
        </PreviewBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(PreviewPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(PreviewContainer)" FramePersistType="2" SlidesUpAndDown="true" layoutpos="top" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(ReadingPane)" layout="filllayout()" layoutpos="right">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="ReadingPaneThumbnailModule" HideProperty="PreviewHandlerRunning" Vertical="true" layoutpos="client" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)"/>
        <ReadingPaneModule ModuleID="ReadingPaneModule" layoutpos="none"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(ReadingPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(ReadingPane)" GrowTargetFirst="true" SlidesUpAndDown="false" PrioritySizer="atom(PageSpaceControlSizer)" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false" FramePersistType="2" layoutpos="Right"/>
        <ProperTreeModule id="atom(ProperTree)" ModuleID="ProperTreeModule" sheet="musiclayoutstyle" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element id="atom(ViewHostContainer)" layoutpos="Client" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layout="borderlayout()">
        <ViewHost id="atom(clientviewhost)" layout="borderlayout()" layoutpos="client">
        </ViewHost>
        </Element>
        </Element>
        </duixml>
        ```
      - 5 > 1033 > Replace text > Compile Script:

        ```
        <duixml>
        <Element resid="FolderLayout" layout="shellborderlayout()" sheet="photolayoutstyle">
        <StatusBarModule ModuleID="StatusBarModule" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()"/>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewContainer)" height="53rp" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()">
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewShineLayer)"/>
        <PreviewBackground id="atom(BackgroundClear)" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)" layout="borderlayout()">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="PreviewThumbnailModule" MaxThumbSize="256" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element layoutpos="Client" layout="filllayout()">
        <PreviewMetadata ModuleID="PreviewMetadataModule" NullSelectPropertyString="prop:*System.OfflineStatus;*System.OfflineAvailability" layoutpos="Client"/>
        </Element>
        </PreviewBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(PreviewPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(PreviewContainer)" FramePersistType="2" SlidesUpAndDown="true" layoutpos="top" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(ReadingPane)" layout="filllayout()" layoutpos="right">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="ReadingPaneThumbnailModule" HideProperty="PreviewHandlerRunning" Vertical="true" layoutpos="client" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)"/>
        <ReadingPaneModule ModuleID="ReadingPaneModule" layoutpos="none"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(ReadingPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(ReadingPane)" GrowTargetFirst="true" SlidesUpAndDown="false" PrioritySizer="atom(PageSpaceControlSizer)" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false" FramePersistType="2" layoutpos="Right"/>
        <ProperTreeModule id="atom(ProperTree)" ModuleID="ProperTreeModule" sheet="photolayoutstyle" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element id="atom(ViewHostContainer)" layoutpos="Client" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layout="borderlayout()">
        <ViewHost id="atom(clientviewhost)" layout="borderlayout()" layoutpos="client">
        </ViewHost>
        </Element>
        </Element>
        </duixml>
        ```
      - 6 > 1033 > Replace text > Compile Script:

        ```
        <duixml>
        <Element resid="FolderLayout" layout="shellborderlayout()" sheet="documentslayoutstyle">
        <StatusBarModule ModuleID="StatusBarModule" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()"/>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewContainer)" height="90rp" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()">
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewShineLayer)"/>
        <PreviewBackground id="atom(BackgroundClear)" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)" layout="borderlayout()">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="PreviewThumbnailModule" MaxThumbSize="256" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element layoutpos="Client" layout="filllayout()">
        <PreviewMetadata ModuleID="PreviewMetadataModule" NullSelectPropertyString="prop:*System.OfflineStatus;*System.OfflineAvailability" layoutpos="Client"/>
        </Element>
        </PreviewBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(PreviewPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(PreviewContainer)" FramePersistType="2" SlidesUpAndDown="true" layoutpos="top" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(ReadingPane)" layout="filllayout()" layoutpos="right">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="ReadingPaneThumbnailModule" HideProperty="PreviewHandlerRunning" Vertical="true" layoutpos="client" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)"/>
        <ReadingPaneModule ModuleID="ReadingPaneModule" layoutpos="none"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(ReadingPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(ReadingPane)" GrowTargetFirst="true" SlidesUpAndDown="false" PrioritySizer="atom(PageSpaceControlSizer)" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false" FramePersistType="2" layoutpos="Right"/>
        <ProperTreeModule id="atom(ProperTree)" ModuleID="ProperTreeModule" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element id="atom(ViewHostContainer)" layoutpos="Client" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layout="borderlayout()">
        <ViewHost id="atom(clientviewhost)" layout="borderlayout()" layoutpos="client">
        </ViewHost>
        </Element>
        </Element>
        </duixml>
        ```
      - 19 > 1033 > Replace text > Compile Script:

        ```
        <duixml>
        <Element resid="FolderLayout" layout="shellborderlayout()" sheet="documentslayoutstyle">
        <StatusBarModule ModuleID="StatusBarModule" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()"/>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewContainer)" height="53rp" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()">
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewShineLayer)"/>
        <PreviewBackground id="atom(BackgroundClear)" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)" layout="borderlayout()">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="PreviewThumbnailModule" MaxThumbSize="256" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element layoutpos="Client" layout="filllayout()">
        <PreviewMetadata ModuleID="PreviewMetadataModule" NullSelectPropertyString="prop:*System.OfflineStatus;*System.OfflineAvailability" layoutpos="Client"/>
        </Element>
        </PreviewBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(PreviewPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(PreviewContainer)" FramePersistType="2" SlidesUpAndDown="true" layoutpos="top" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(ReadingPane)" layout="filllayout()" layoutpos="right">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="ReadingPaneThumbnailModule" HideProperty="PreviewHandlerRunning" Vertical="true" layoutpos="client"/>
        <ReadingPaneModule ModuleID="ReadingPaneModule" layoutpos="none"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(ReadingPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(ReadingPane)" GrowTargetFirst="true" SlidesUpAndDown="false" PrioritySizer="atom(PageSpaceControlSizer)" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false" FramePersistType="2" layoutpos="Right"/>
        <ProperTreeModule id="atom(ProperTree)" ModuleID="ProperTreeModule" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element id="atom(ViewHostContainer)" layoutpos="Client" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layout="borderlayout()">
        <ViewHost id="atom(clientviewhost)" layout="borderlayout()" layoutpos="client">
        </ViewHost>
        </Element>
        </Element>
        </duixml>
        ```
      - 20 > 1033 > Replace text > Compile Script:

        ```
        <duixml>
        <Element resid="FolderLayout" layout="shellborderlayout()" sheet="documentslayoutstyle">
        <StatusBarModule ModuleID="StatusBarModule" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()"/>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewContainer)" height="53rp" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()">
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewShineLayer)"/>
        <PreviewBackground id="atom(BackgroundClear)" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)" layout="borderlayout()">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="PreviewThumbnailModule" MaxThumbSize="256" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element layoutpos="Client" layout="filllayout()">
        <PreviewMetadata ModuleID="PreviewMetadataModule" NullSelectPropertyString="prop:*System.OfflineStatus;*System.OfflineAvailability" layoutpos="Client"/>
        </Element>
        </PreviewBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(PreviewPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(PreviewContainer)" FramePersistType="2" SlidesUpAndDown="true" layoutpos="top" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(ReadingPane)" layout="filllayout()" layoutpos="right">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="ReadingPaneThumbnailModule" HideProperty="PreviewHandlerRunning" Vertical="true" layoutpos="client" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)"/>
        <ReadingPaneModule ModuleID="ReadingPaneModule" layoutpos="none"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(ReadingPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(ReadingPane)" GrowTargetFirst="true" SlidesUpAndDown="false" PrioritySizer="atom(PageSpaceControlSizer)" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false" FramePersistType="2" layoutpos="Right"/>
        <ProperTreeModule id="atom(ProperTree)" ModuleID="ProperTreeModule" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element id="atom(ViewHostContainer)" layoutpos="Client" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layout="borderlayout()">
        <ViewHost id="atom(clientviewhost)" layout="borderlayout()" layoutpos="client">
        </ViewHost>
        </Element>
        </Element>
        </duixml>
        ```
      - 21 > 1033 > Replace text > Compile Script:

        ```
        <duixml>
        <Element resid="FolderLayout" layout="shellborderlayout()" sheet="genericlayoutstyle">
        <StatusBarModule ModuleID="StatusBarModule" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()"/>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewContainer)" height="53rp" layoutpos="bottom" layout="filllayout()">
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(PreviewShineLayer)"/>
        <PreviewBackground id="atom(BackgroundClear)" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)" layout="borderlayout()">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="PreviewThumbnailModule" MaxThumbSize="256" layoutpos="Left"/>
        <Element layoutpos="Client" layout="filllayout()">
        <PreviewMetadata ModuleID="PreviewMetadataModule" NullSelectTitlePropertyString="prop:System.Computer.SimpleName;*System.Computer.Description" NullSelectPropertyString="prop:*System.Computer.DomainName;*System.Computer.Workgroup;*System.Computer.Processor;System.Computer.Memory" layoutpos="Client"/>
        </Element>
        </PreviewBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(PreviewPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(PreviewContainer)" SlidesUpAndDown="true" layoutpos="top" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <TemplateBackground id="atom(ReadingPane)" layout="filllayout()" layoutpos="right">
        <PreviewThumbnail ModuleID="ReadingPaneThumbnailModule" HideProperty="PreviewHandlerRunning" Vertical="true" layoutpos="client" background="ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)"/>
        <ReadingPaneModule ModuleID="ReadingPaneModule" layoutpos="none"/>
        </TemplateBackground>
        <Sizer id="atom(ReadingPaneSizer)" sizingtarget="atom(ReadingPane)" GrowTargetFirst="true" SlidesUpAndDown="false" PrioritySizer="atom(PageSpaceControlSizer)" DownOrRightGrowsTarget="false" FramePersistType="2" layoutpos="Right"/>
        <ProperTreeModule id="atom(ProperTree)" ModuleID="ProperTreeModule" sheet="documentslayoutstyle" layoutpos="Left" RootMgrClsid="{93319CCC-B277-48FF-95BD-6CDCCAFCBD31}"/>
        <Element id="atom(ViewHostContainer)" layoutpos="Client" sheet="genericlayoutstyle" layout="filllayout()">
        <ViewHost id="atom(clientviewhost)" layout="borderlayout()">
        </ViewHost>
        </Element>
        </Element>
        </duixml>
        ```
    - File > Save.
    - File > Exit.
  - Copy the modified `shell32.dll` to its system directory.

    - Right click on the Start corner > Command Prompt (Admin) > Yes.

      - Type:

        ```
        cd %SystemDirectory%
        copy %DllPath%
        ```

        - While typing, replace `%SystemDirectory%` with `shell32.dll`'s system directory and `%DllPath%` with the path of the `shell32.dll` file.
      - Verify that `shell32.dll` exists in its system directory.

        - Type:

          ```
          dir "shell32.dll"
          ```
      - Close the command prompt.
- Charms bar > Settings > Power > Restart.

### Sources

- Detailbereich -details pane- im Explorer wieder nach unten setzen Windows 8 – Deskmodder Wiki:

  http://www.deskmodder.de/wiki/index.php/Detailbereich_-details_pane-_im_Explorer_wieder_nach_unten_setzen_Windows_8

### Disadvantages

The downside that I have noticed so far is that explorer operations that require elevation will prompt user account control (UAC) dialogs with "unknown publisher". However, this is not a big deal for me because I do not need to edit protected files so often, and the benefit of having the details pane outweighs the disadvantage.

Comment: It works! But everytime I open an x64 app (example: Adobe Photoshop CS5), i get error 0xC000007B - is that normal?

Answer (score 14):

Windows 8 has a **Details Pane** that show the details of video files. To open the Details Pane

1. From the Ribbon on File Explorer, click on View
2. Select Details Pane

[image]

**Response to EDIT:** It seems the Details pane can not be brought to the bottom as of now. I would guess Microsoft based this design decision on the fact that most people use Widescreen displays these days, and the Details Pane (along with the new Ribbon) would take up a lot of the vertical space.

Comment: That logic makes me angry. Just because I have a wide screen monitor does not mean I open my explorer windows at full screen. In fact, quite the opposite. It makes me want to tile my windows, so my window is now taller and narrower than if I had a 4:3 monitor. I have LESS horizontal space!

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative provided - The `Details pane`. It works quite similar, except that it can enabled at the right side of your screen (You can toggle between Preview pane and Details pane)

[image]

Example:

[image]

Comment: Actually the details pane isn't an alternative, it's *exactly the same* as in Windows 7.

Comment: There are few small differences - one being, you can only toggle between Preview & Details pane. And second, the status bar still exists - Options -> Show Status bar. And hence i called this an alternative.

Comment: And if you look at the Question description (-> Edit), you'll see that   it asks for the Status bar, even though Details pane exists as an "alternative".

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool that will do the modifications shown above for you. Check out "OldNewExplorer".

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-make-your-81-explorer-work-like-win78-one/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.