# Windows 8.1 - How to Edit Details in Windows Explorer Columns

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

In XP, I could right click on any file, select properties, go to summary tab and I would have some columns to edit, e.g. Title, Author, Category ect.

In this example, see images below, I've give each file a category of sport.

I could then right click and select Arrange Icons By Category, and Show in Groups, and all the files would be shown in category groups.

In Win 8.1, when I right click on a file, I don't get the summary view, just General, Security, Details.

I know I can right click in 8.1 and use Sort By and Group By, but how do I edit the column details like Categories ect., as I would have done in the Summary tab in XP?

E.g. I might want to add year to these movies:

[image: movies]

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Answer (score 0):

The Details tab has been moved to the Details pane in Windows 8. You can turn it on as follows:

1. On the File Explorer ribbon, select the **View** tab
2. In the *Panes* group, select **Details pane**

This will open the Details pane where you can access the details for the file currently selected in the File Explorer window.

Credit to this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/494883/213131).

Comment: But how do I edit the column details - eg year in the movie example?

Comment: You should be able to [edit them directly in the details pane](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1963993&seqNum=20).  Can you edit details for *any* file type?

Comment: I can't edit any details at all on videos, like flv or mkv.    I can edit images ok, but only a set number (14) of categories such as date taken, title, comments, authors. I can't add more - if if I right click on the categories bar and select more and add more categories , eg year, I can't edit them.